# cant open certificate store

Tags: c#, x509certificate2

I need to load certificate from certificate store:

```
using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
{
     store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
     var certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, certificateName, false);
     if (certs == null || certs.Count == 0)
     {
                    ...
     }

     return certs[0];
}
```

but sometimes when callling store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly); exception is thrown

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: An internal error
> occurred.    at
> System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store.Open(OpenFlags
> flags)

User have permissions to open store and most of the time opening store is successfull, only sometimes it fails.

Comment: Have a look at the exception. There should be an InnerException with more details, and hopefully a Windows error code?

Comment: Is your if statement wrong :  if (certs != null && certs.Count > 0)

Comment: @Rup no inner exception is present and i also look to event viewer and also no error

Comment: @jdweng when it reach if everything is correct, exception is thron at store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

Comment: OK, skimming the .NET Framework reference source it looks like the error code is on the CryptographicException, the HResult property. (Although if it's 0x8007054f = ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR then that's no extra help.)

Comment: Can you get a stack trace?  I  do not think the certificate exists. To stop exception you can use following flags in case it doesn't exist :OpenFlags flags = OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.IncludeArchived;

Comment: @jdweng certificate exist, it crash at open store, load certificate is next step. if I call it with certificate name that does not exist, it doesn't throw exception, but return empty collection.

Comment: From cmd.exe use Regex and check location of certificate in Local Machine and Current User.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/local-machine-and-current-user-certificate-stores

Comment: Key has to be in both LocalMachine and CurrentUser.  See Open method : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/security/system/security/cryptography/x509/x509store.cs,5f32dc1ea67a9cb7

Comment: yes certificate is present also in local machine and in current user store (under trusted people)